# How can I configure claim authentication in a separate asp.net mvc authentication website with Thinktecture 2 with friendly user login page?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, wif, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong with this approach for single sing on?

I have a website A with the authentication logic inside. The user can select the role to access the portal that he wants to go. The problem is how can I configure properly those websites to redirect correctly, because when I redirect, I lose the token(redirect is a GET), I never had the cookie on the portal that I want to go. Do I am missing something in my implementation? Maybe a configuration on the portal that I want to redirect? I am not using the audienceUri on the webconfig, Is this related with the problem? I am using a service that gives me a token if the user is authenticated. Then with that token, I want to redirect the page to the corresponding portal.

[image]

[image]

Said that I will show you the Login Method in AccountController

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string ddlRoles, string ddlUrls, LoginModel user)
    {
        var service = new AuthenticationServiceAgent(user.Username, user.Password);
        var securityService = new SecurityServiceAgent(service.GetToken());

       ...processing the claims
       //AT THIS POINT THE USER IS AUTHENTICATED
       FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(token, true);
       .... get the url to redirect 
      Response.Redirect(urlToRedirect, false);
    }
```

My Proxy class looks like this

```
public class UserNameTokenServiceProxy : TokenServiceProxy
    {
        #region Properties

        public SecurityCredential Credential { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        public override SecurityToken GetToken(ISecurityCredential credential = null)
        {
            if (null == credential)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("credential");
            }

            var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
                new EndpointAddress(StsEndPoint)
            );

            factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

            if (null != factory.Credentials)
            {
                factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = credential.UserName;
                factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = credential.Password;
            }

            var rst = new RequestSecurityToken()
            {
                RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
                KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
                TokenType = TokenTypes.Saml11TokenProfile11,
                ***********RelyingPartyUri comes from a config file*********
                AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(RelyingPartyUri)
            };

            try
            {
                var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
                var sToken = channel.Issue(rst);

                return sToken;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```

And the base class of that one is the following:

```
public abstract class TokenServiceProxy
{
    #region Fields

    protected string StsEndPoint;
    protected string RelyingPartyUri;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    protected TokenServiceProxy()
    {
        StsEndPoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["stsEndpoint"];
        if (null == StsEndPoint)
        {
            throw new Exception("STSEndPoint cannot be null");
        }

        RelyingPartyUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["relyingPartyUri"];
        if (null == RelyingPartyUri)
        {
            throw new Exception("RelyingPartyUri cannot be null");
        }
        //StsEndPoint = <add key="stsEndpoint" value="https://sso.dev.MyCompany.com/idsrv/issue/wstrust/mixed/username"/>;
        //RelyingPartyUri = @"value="https://dev.MyCompany.com/MyCompanyPortal"/>";
    }

    #endregion

    #region Abstract Methods

    public abstract SecurityToken GetToken(ISecurityCredential credential = null);

    #endregion

}
```

Basically we are not using the default configuration for WS with the audienceUri and the federationConfiguration section, the equivalent would be:

```
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler mode="Default" requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://sso.dev.MyCompany.com/idsrv/issue/wstrust/mixed/username" realm="https://dev.MyCompany.com/MyCompanyPortal" requireHttps="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

Comment: Can you also show your web.config settings, specifically the `microsoft.identityModel` section?

Comment: @GarrettVlieger I put more details at the end of the example

Comment: @GarrettVlieger basically we are using a proxy to retrieve the token, AuthenticationServiceAgent internally  pass via contructor a ISecurityCredential to an instance of UserNameTokenServiceProxy and everybody that use that service obtains the token

Comment: How can I pass that token with a redirect? This doesn't work for me Response.Redirect(urlToRedirect, false)

Comment: Do I need to create a cookie manually? If that is the case, wich name I need to put and what value to consider it when I am trying to redirect make the proper check  "if (FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.ContainsSessionTokenCookie(Request.Cookies))"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what are all the components in your solution, but in any case you seem to try to do too much on your own.
SSO or not - each integrated application needs to maintain its own authentication state (with authentication cookie), and to do so it needs to get the security token from Identity Provider.
In a most common scenario for WS-Federation (Relying Party initiated SSO), Relying Party application redirects user to Identity Provider, Identity Provider checks user credentials and POSTS security token back to Relying Party application, where it is handled by WS-Federation module to create authentication cookie.
In your case I guess that you are trying to achieve "Identity Provider initiated" SSO (assuming, that your login page is part of Identity Provider).
If this is the case, you need to POST created security token to selected Relying Party (as far as I know WS-Federation does not support sending tokens in GET query string). 
Of course you need to have proper WS-Federation configuration on your Relying Party side to accept this token and create authentication cookie - having that the authentication is done automatically by WS-Federation module.

Comment: In my scenario I have a service that request a token for itself, every application included my websites can request a token via that service(the relaying party on this case will be same for all because the service is the only one who make a call to the identity provider, so the relying party is the service) . Every webapplication pass the correct credentials to the webservice that takes care of the authentication and responds with a token. So the configuration that points directly to the STS is on the webservice, no under my websites.

Comment: I need the FedAuth cookie to be present on website B after my redirect from website A to website B. Remember I am not going to the authentication page of the Identity Provider, instead I call my service.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, you don't use "pasive redirection" SSO mode at all. In such a case you need to pass "something" from application A to application B, that it will allow application B to authenticate user without requesting his/hers credentials.

Comment: This "something" may be the token itself (in theory - if token is signed by STS certificate - it may be enough to make it secure), or it may be some "session token" used only to communicate with STS to obtain a valid "authentication token" from STS per application. In any case you need to handle this "something" pretty much on your own.

Comment: The thing is that every website lose its session after a redirect, so is too tricky to persist the cookie with all the values that the STS puts on it. Actually I that is the main problem if I will not rely on the authentication page of the STS.

Comment: "Session token" is just a name - you would need to introduce some mechanism to create and maintain it in STS - for sure it would not be a regular session cookie for example, as it cannot be shared between applications from different domains. Unfortunatelly I don't have any meaningful experience with the "active client" SSO scenario you have chosen, so I cannot give you a straight answer :-(. The "passive redirection" configuration is way more popular with web apps - and probably for a reason...